# Blinking when swapping JPanel content

Tags: java, swing, jpanel, java-3d

I'm working on a project using Java3D and Jmol (it's a viewer for chemical structures in 3D). I have to create view that is able to switch between Java3D and Jmol representation of structures.

I have managed to do that, but when I swap JPanels with JmolPanel and Canvas3D in them, I get blinking of the swapped area.

I'm swapping panels simply by doing:

```
public static void changeView(JPanel c) {
     c.removeAll();
    if (var) {
        c.add(canvas);
    } else {
        c.add(jmolPanel);
    }
    c.revalidate();
    var = !var;
}
```

An example of code that creates frame with button for swapping panels can be found here: http://pastebin.com/3F2gKBgb

To run this example you need Jmol.jar (it can be found here http://jmol.sourceforge.net/download/) and Java3D (http://java3d.java.net/binary-builds.html)

I tried setting double buffering in JPanels, but it doesn't help. Do you have any idea how the blinking problem could be resolved?

Comment: It seems that I also need a Windows PC to run that code (my Mac does not have a C:/ drive). That being said, take a look at the `CardLayout` class which is designed to switch between different views

Comment: @Robin It's just a path to j3dcore-ogl.dll file (Java3D installation). If you swap it to Mac path, it'll probably work (or you don't need this at all - maybe it's just problem with my config).
I changed the layout as you've suggested, but I still get the blinking. Code changing content of my panel now looks like this (I don't know if you can do anything more with it):
 `public static void changeView(JPanel c) {  
  CardLayout cl = (CardLayout) c.getLayout();  
  if (var) {
   cl.show(c, "canvas");
  } else {
   cl.show(c, "jmol");
  }
  var = !var;
 }`

Comment: If I recall correctly (it's begin a while), the 3D canvass tend to be heavy weight components. The blinking could be an ratification of the switch between heavy and light weight components, if so, there may not be anyone you can do. Ensure that you switching the components within I. The EDT

Comment: @MadProgrammer I modified my code so it'd be switching everything in the EDT, thanks for the reminder:). So I guess in this case the only solution to mask blinking is setting a black background. I just hoped I would be able to solve the problem when changing the whole content of frame, not just this single panel... Anyway thanks for your help.

Answer (score 0):

If by blinking you mean it's getting repainted while you are removing and then adding sub-panel then I would try to stop repainting, do all the swapping and then enable repainting of the parent panel.

May be the 
`c.setVisible(false); <your swapping code>; c.setVisible(true);` 
will help?

or create a subpanel sc, that you will make invisible to which you will add your swappable components, so that the parent panel stays visible at all times. It may be a hack around double-buffering problem that should have solved your problem to begin with, but it's worth a try.

Comment: setVisible() unfortunately doesn't help. What do you exactly mean by subpanel? Right now I add my viewPanel (kind of a parent panel - it's the 'c' panel in changeView()) to content pane and this viewPanel is always visible.